# How to connect my c# programme to a text file and edit parameters

Tags: c#, text, parameters, edit, using

I created an application which has 2 labels and 1 textbox.
The first label will show the total number of days since the year began, while the second shows the number of tests in the year. In the textbox shows the number of tests that I have not studied.

When the program opens, you have to click a button to load an .txt file to get these numbers, they are saved when you exit by clicking in another button. I Wanted to know how to load the file and to save the parameters.

I'm developing in C#, grateful, sorry for bad english.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We don't make a habit of doing your work for you here, and instead use a more collaborative approach to helping you.  That being said, quid-pro-cuo, please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read text use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
```

To write text use [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx)

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.ToArray());
```

Or some variation on those methods to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be this:

```
using System.IO;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      // Do stuff with your line here, it will be called for each 
      // line of text in your file.
   }
}
```

Or, you could do:

```
List<String> txtStrings = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
```

Or, come up with your own approach by reading up on [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx).